# How to refactor snippet of old JSP to some JSF equivalent?

Tags: jsp, jsf, facelets, composite-component

**ORIGINAL JSP** (WorkItem.jsp)

```
<c:forEach var="actionItem" items="${workItem.work_action_list}">
    <c:if test="${actionItem.workActionClass.work_action_type_id == '1'}" >
       <%@ include file="inc_done_button.jsp" %>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${actionItem.workActionClass.work_action_type_id == '2'}" >
         <c:set var="actionItem" value="${actionItem}" scope="request" />
         <c:set var="checklist" value="${actionItem.meat}" scope="request" />
        <jsp:include page="inc_dynamic_checklist_v.jsp" flush="true" />
    </c:if>
    etc...
</c:forEach>
```

**ORIGINAL Java**

```
for (ListIterator<WorkflowInstanceWorkItemAction> actionIter = wfiwi.getWork_action_list().listIterator(); actionIter.hasNext();) {
    if ("2".equals(work_action_type_id)) {
        ChecklistInstanceForm ciForm = new ChecklistInstanceForm(this, authenticatedUser);
         ChecklistInstance ci = null; 
        ci = (ChecklistInstance) ciForm.getChkLstInstanceByWfiWiaOwner(wfiWorkItemAction, authenticatedUser);
    // Get the meat details for this action and inject it into the object
        wfiWorkItemAction.setMeat(ci);
    }
}

request.setAttribute("workItem", wfiwi);
request.setAttribute("workFlowInstance", wfi);
```

**NEW JSF** (WorkItem.xhtml)

```
 <f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="wfi_wid" value="#{workItemController.wfiwi}" converter="#{workItemConverter}"
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{workItemController.preRender}" />
 </f:metadata>
<ui:repeat var="actionItem" value="#{workItemController.wfiwi.work_action_list}">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{actionItem.workActionClass.workActionType.action_type_id == '1'}">
        <stk:done_button actionItem="#{actionItem}" /> <!-- Here I chose custom c -->
    </ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{actionItem.workActionClass.workActionType.action_type_id == '2'}">
                <ui:include src="inc_dynamic_checklist.xhtml">
                    <ui:param name="checklist" value="#{actionItem.meat}" />
                </ui:include>
    </ui:fragment>
```

**The makings of my new backing bean**

```
public class WorkItemController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private WorkflowInstanceWorkItem wfiwi;

    public void preRender() {
    if (wfiwi.getWork_action_list() != null) {
            //loop through and add real model to meat attribute
```

What I am after is a more elegant way to inject the model (what I am calling meat) into my view for each action.  Under a work item (single page view), there are multiple actions.  Actions that are checklists can be of various types (yes/no/na, quantity major/minor, yes/no/na/resolved,  etc).

The composite component `done_button` was straight forward because I am only accessing the base `action` model and no `meat`. For example a snippet of the `done_button.xhtml` composite component

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{cc.attrs.actionItem.is_active != '1'}">
     Action is not active for you until the following has been completed:
     <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.actionItem.prerequisite_work_action_list}" escapeXml="false" />
</ui:fragment>
```

but the include of the dynamic_checklist facelet code has me perplexed because my approach of injecting various `Objects` into this generic attribute `meat` :) seems wrong.  In my original JSP I used `<c:set var="checklist" value="${actionItem.meat}" scope="request" />` and then the original JSP for `inc_dynamic_checklist_v.jsp` looked something like

**inc_dynamic_checklist_v.jsp**

```
<form method="post" >

<c:out value="${actionItem.workActionClass.name}" /> 

<c:if test="${checklist.checkListClass.type == '1'}" >
  <%@ include file="inc_yes_no_na_resolved_checklist.jsp" %>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${checklist.checkListClass.type == '2'}" >
  <%@ include file="inc_major_minor_checklist.jsp" %>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${checklist.checkListClass.type == '3'}" >
  <%@ include file="inc_quantity_checklist.jsp" %>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${checklist.checkListClass.type == '4'}" >
  <%@ include file="inc_yes_no_na_checklist.jsp" %>
</c:if>
```

those includes also needed access to the actionItem.meat which was set using c:set in WorkItem.jsp

I'm looking for guidance as to yes I should convert all these includes into composite components, even though I have nested includes.  Or I should use basic ui:includes?  I know I can send `param` with either include or cc but do I still use the generic field `private Object meat` in my model or is there a better way to retrieve these individual action models.

perhaps this but it didn't work

```
<ui:include src="inc_dynamic_checklist.xhtml" >
    <ui:param name="wfi_id" value="#{actionItem.workflowInstance.workflow_instance_id}" />
    <ui:param name="wfi_aid" value="#{actionItem.wfi_work_item_action_id}" />
</ui:include>
```

and then in the inc_dynamic_checklist.xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="wfi_id" value="#{checklistInstanceView.ci}" converter="#{checklistInstanceConverter}">
        <f:attribute name="wfi_id" value="#{param.wfi_id}" />
        <f:attribute name="wfi_aid" value="#{param.wfi_aid}" />
    </o:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
```

**UPDATE**

Work item backing bean. A work Item contains an array of actions.  Actions can be done buttons (action type id=1) checklists (action type id=2), and other things not implemented/shown.   What I have now works but is it the right way?

```
public void preRender() {
if (wfiwi.getWork_action_list() != null) {

    for (ListIterator<WorkflowInstanceWorkItemAction> actionIter = wfiwi.getWork_action_list().listIterator(); actionIter.hasNext();) {

        WorkflowInstanceWorkItemAction wfiWorkItemAction = new WorkflowInstanceWorkItemAction();
        wfiWorkItemAction = actionIter.next();

        Long work_action_type_id = wfiWorkItemAction.getWorkActionClass().getWorkActionType().getAction_type_id();

        updatePrerequisites(wfiWorkItemAction, wfiwi.getWorkflowInstance(), wfiwi);

        if (work_action_type_id == 2) {
            System.out.println("Action Type 2 is Dynamic Checklist Type");
            ci = ciRepository.retrieveLatestByWfiWiai(wfiwi.getWorkflowInstance().getWorkflow_instance_id(), wfiWorkItemAction.getWfi_work_item_action_id());

            if (ci != null) {
                if ("1".equals(ci.getCheckListClass().getType())) {
                    List<YesNoNaResolvedAnswer> answer_attribute_list = yesNoNaResolvedDao.retrieveByCiWfi(ci.getChecklist_instance_id(), ci.getWorkflowInstance().getWorkflow_instance_id());
                    ci.setAnswer_attribute_list(answer_attribute_list);
                }

                if ("2".equals(ci.getCheckListClass().getType())) {
                    List<MajorMinorAnswer> answer_attribute_list = majorMinorAnsDao.retrieveByCiWfi(ci.getChecklist_instance_id(), ci.getWorkflowInstance().getWorkflow_instance_id());
                    ci.setAnswer_attribute_list(answer_attribute_list);
                }

                if ("3".equals(ci.getCheckListClass().getType())) {
                    List<QuantityAnswer> answer_attribute_list = quantityAnsDao.retrieveByCiWfi(ci.getChecklist_instance_id(), ci.getWorkflowInstance().getWorkflow_instance_id());
                    ci.setAnswer_attribute_list(answer_attribute_list);
                }
                if ("4".equals(ci.getCheckListClass().getType())) {
                    List<YesNoNaAnswer> answer_attribute_list = yesNoNaAnsDao.retrieveByCiWfi(ci.getChecklist_instance_id(), ci.getWorkflowInstance().getWorkflow_instance_id());
                    ci.setAnswer_attribute_list(answer_attribute_list);
                }

                wfiWorkItemAction.setMeat(ci);
            } else {
                Messages.addFlashErrorMessage("Could not find checklist Instance");
            }

            // wfi_action_list.add(ci);
        } else {
            wfiWorkItemAction.setMeat("meat pie");
        }
    }
}
```

}

inc_dynamic_checklist.xhtml (see WorkItem.xhtm above for how this is included) This is displaying the "meat"

```
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{checklist.checkListClass.type == '1'}">
        <ui:include src="inc_yes_no_na_resolved_checklist.xhtml" />
    </ui:fragment>

    <ui:fragment rendered="#{checklist.checkListClass.type == '2'}">
        <ui:include src="inc_major_minor_checklist.xhtml" />
    </ui:fragment>

    <ui:fragment rendered="${checklist.checkListClass.type == '3'}">
        <ui:include src="inc_quantity_checklist.xhtml" />
    </ui:fragment>

    <ui:fragment rendered="${checklist.checkListClass.type == '4'}">
        <ui:include src="inc_yes_no_na_checklist.xhtml" />
    </ui:fragment>
```

model

```
@Entity
public class WorkflowInstanceWorkItemAction implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String status;
private String is_active;

@Transient
private Object meat; 
and various mappings
```

Comment: You are not supposed to focus on converting JSPs to JSF equivalent. Start afresh with JSF.

Comment: Isn't that what my question is asking - How to do it the JSF way?  You can't totally throw out focusing or thinking about the old JSPs because what the JSPs achieved for you in the old app is what you want the JSF to do for you in the new app.

Comment: Experts mention quite often that  JSP is a deprecated technology in favour of Facelets. The way how JSF works is changed drastically since then. I am not going beyond that scope.

Comment: I couldn't immediately boil down the concrete functional requirement (so the question is kinda too broad), so here's a link which gives hopefully some guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen

Comment: @BalusC thanks....I've started a bounty for you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One step at a time.

It's important that everything keeps working as intented before advancing to next step.

---

#### Keep using JSTL to dynamically build the view

Just keep using JSTL and only replace JSP includes by `<ui:include>` until you get it all to work. Don't change too much yet. First get it all working and then refactor into tagfiles or composites.

In your initial JSP approach you're basically dynamically building the view with help of JSTL. You can just continue doing the same in JSF 2.x, provided that you're using a more recent JSF impl version to prevent broken view scoped beans (Mojarra 2.1.18+). You can keep using `<c:forEach>`, `<c:if>` and `<c:set>` this way in JSF. You only need to replace `@include` and `<jsp:include>` by `<ui:include>`. Do note that `<ui:include>` has the same lifecycle as JSTL. It's also a taghandler and not a component. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

The `<ui:fragment>`, however, is an UI component. It does not conditionally build the view. Regardless of the outcome of its `rendered` attribute, it and all of its children will still end up in JSF component tree. They will only conditionally render their HTML output during render response phase. The payoff as compared to `<c:if>` is that the JSF component tree size will grow for every condition. It would grow at least 4 times as big, given that you've 4 conditional includes in that `inc_dynamic_checklist_v` file. Just keep using JSTL to dynamically build the view. It's a perfectly fine tool for that. See also a.o. [How to make a grid of JSF composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713718/how-to-make-a-grid-of-jsf-composite-component/5716633#5716633) The alternative would be to manually create components in backing bean via `binding`, `findComponent()`, `createComponent()`, `new SomeComponent()`, `getChildren().add()` and what not and this would only end up in verbose and brittle code which is hard to maintain. Absolutely don't do that.

The `<f|o:viewParam>` as shown in your failed attempt serves a different purpose. They can't act on `<ui:param>` values from the `<ui:include>`, as you seemed to expect. They act only on HTTP request parameters. See also [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for) You can for your `<ui:include>` keep using `<ui:param>` instead of `<c:set>`, but you should just be accessing them directly, like as you did with `<c:set>`. The only difference is that those variables are only available inside the include itself instead of in the entire request (i.e. thus also outside the include). The JSP equivalent of `<ui:param>` is by the way `<jsp:param>`, which you actually should have used in first place.

As to backing bean logic, just put the pre-processing Java code in `@PostConstruct` of the backing bean and the post-processing Java code in action methods of backing bean, tied to `<h:commandXxx>` components. The `<f:viewAction>` and `preRenderView` are insuitable because they run far after view build time and thus JSTL wouldn't get the model it expects. Use those only to process user-submitted HTTP request parameters.

If you're bitten by the chicken-egg view state bug in an older Mojarra version and you absolutely can't upgrade, nor can disable the partial state saving by setting `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` to `false`, then you can't attach JSTL tag attributes to view scoped bean properties. If you've indeed a view scoped bean here, and it's not an option to use a request scoped bean here, you'd need to drop JSTL and exclusively use `<ui:repeat>` and `<ui:fragment>` instead of `<c:forEach>` and `<c:if>`. You can however keep using `<c:set>` (where applicable). You should also keep the guidelines for backing bean logic as described above.

---

#### Refactor repeated include-with-params to tagfiles

Once you get it all to work, then you can start looking at repeated include-with-params (i.e. `<ui:include><ui:param>` chunks which are used more than once) and refactor them to tagfiles by simply registering them in `your.taglib.xml` file. This actually doesn't change anything as to the logic and flow, but makes the code more clean and concise. See also [How to create a custom Facelets tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751624/custom-tags-in-facelets) for complete `*.taglib.xml` example and registration in `web.xml`.

This fictive example include of a "yes/no/na checklist"

```
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/tristateChecklist.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="value" value="#{actionItem}" />
</ui:include>
```

... could be used as below

```
<my:tristateChecklist value="#{actionItem}" />
```

... after moving the physical file into `/WEB-INF/tags/tristateChecklist.xhtml` and registering it in `/WEB-INF/your.taglib.xml` as below with all include params as tag attributes.

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>tristateChecklist</tag-name>
    <source>tags/tristateChecklist.xhtml</source>
    <attribute>
        <name>value</name>
        <type>java.lang.Object</type><!-- TODO: fix type -->
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

*(you didn't show your model, so I just specified an overly generic type)*

---

#### Refactor repeated model pre/post-processing to composites

Once you get it all to work again, then you can start looking at repeated model pre/post-processing and refactor them into composites with a "backing component", along with the associated XHTML inside `<cc:implementation>`.

Basically, when you have quite some Java code in `@PostConstruct` to convert the "external" model as returned by the service/DB to the "internal" model as exactly expected by the view, and/or when you have quite some Java code in action method to convert the "internal" model back to the "external" model as the service/DB expects, then you could consider refactoring it into a reusable composite component. This way you don't need to copypaste/repeat this pre/post-processing task into a different backing bean when you want to reuse the same functionality in a different view. And, you end up with a view which refers exactly the "external" model type instead of "internal" one, possibly consisting of multiple properies.

This part is hard to answer with an example for your specific case without having a full overview of all your model pre/post-processing. The below answers contain examples which should provide sufficient insight on the sense and nonsense of composite components:

- [Split java.util.Date over two h:inputText fields representing hour and minute with f:convertDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235721/split-java-util-date-over-two-hinputtext-fields-representing-hour-and-minute-wi)
- [Initialize a composite component based on the provided attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525669/initialize-a-composite-component-based-on-the-provided-attributes)
- [#{cc.clientId} evalutated in wrong composite after upgrading to JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017598/cc-clientid-evalutated-in-wrong-composite-after-upgrading-to-jsf-2-2/)

At least, I have the impression that your "meat" could be an interface. If you have different objects/classes with same common behavior, then you should create an interface defining that common behavior and have those classes implement that interface. This part is in turn not strictly JSF related, but just "basic" Java.

---

Don't forget: one step at a time.

Use tagfiles and composites as a refactoring tool to minimize code duplication. You should already have fully working code.

Comment: "*nonsense of composite components*"?

Comment: @Tiny: *"the sense and nonsense"*. When they make sense or not. When they are the right tool for the job or not. The "nonsense" part is hopefully clearly explained in the 3rd link.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks. Let me digest this more thoroughly, But for starters 1) I couldn't keep using <c:if and <c:forEach bcause we have Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401). But no problem converting to <ui:repeat> and <ui:fragment>.

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: [Upgrade Mojarra in JBoss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085717/upgrade-and-use-mojarra-as-the-jsf-implementation-with-jboss-server). You really don't want to have that chicken-egg view state bug.

Comment: I'm not seeing the bloat with <ui:fragment>. Using <ui:repeat> and <ui:fragment rendered="condition" I then checked debug and component tree but only saw that code when the condition was true.

Comment: remember I was the guy still using JSP years after that were out of style.... I don't have full control over the server installation and configuration. I can put request in but it won't be their priority.  Either way if I stay away from <c: won't I not have any issue?  Seems to work using <ui:

Comment: You can do so, provided that you follow same backing bean logic as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: chipping away...  All your steps make sense -  actually was already doing some of these things.  It's really the "meat" which I need help.  It's like what I want is an iteration over multiple backing beans and views.  Think of it like I create a backing bean and view for a "yes_no_na_resolved_checklist" which takes url parameters. I do the same for "inc_major_minor_checklist",  "inc_quantity_checklist", etc . Now I iterate over an array of actions which can have any, all, or some of these checklists as the main ("meat") of the "action".  Will update my Q, But so far your A is very helpful.

Comment: I honestly think you should accelt the answer. Adding this much new detail should be a new Q

Comment: jeff, that part is honestly "just" Java. Think of command pattern and (abstract) interfaces. E.g. in that `if (ci != null)` block you should be able to end up with an oneliner like `wfiWorkItemAction.setMeat(ci.setAnswer_attribute_list(allDaos.get(ci.getCheckListClass().getType()).retrieveByCiWfi(ci.getChecklist_instance_id(), ci.getWorkflowInstance().getWorkflow_instance_id())))` where `allDaos` is a prepopulated `Map<String, SomeAbstractDao>`. And then advance refactoring repeated boilerplate.